# Text of input is valid always

Tags: html, regex, css

I'm going to realize input of text like this:

```
<input type="text"  maxlength="16" required/>
```

And want to use valid and invalid stations like this:

```
input:invalid {
    background: #fdd; 
}
input:valid {
    background: #dfd; 
}
```

But when i write any text my input is valid always. I tried use `pattern`:

```
pattern=".{16,}"
```

But that did not solve anything. Where is my mistake?

The input must be valid when length of input is equal to 16.

Comment: maxlength does not validate the input. It just restricts the amount of characters you can input. In my mind your code is working as it is supposed to: the invalid style is applied if the input is empty ("required" is not fulfulled)

Comment: Do you want to have a maximum or minimum length of 16?

Comment: @Siavas Yes. I want to have valid input when length equal 16.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close! Here's how to do it.

**Allowing only alphanumerics**

```html
<form>
  <input id="username" type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]{16}" required>
  <input id="submit" type="submit" value="create">
</form>
```

---

**Allowing any character**

```html
<form>
  <input id="username" type="text" pattern=".{16}" maxlength="16" required>
  <input id="submit" type="submit" value="create">
</form>
```

**With jQuery mask() plugin**

Here, we just force the delimiter to be part of the input value followed by the number of characters in each group. In this case 4 numbers followed by a space.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#username').mask('9999 9999 9999 9999');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.0/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <input id="username" type="text" pattern="[0-9]{4} [0-9]{4} [0-9]{4} [0-9]{4}" required>
  <input id="submit" type="submit" value="create">
</form>
```

For more info about regex and patterns, check out [Regexr](http://regexr.com).

Comment: Thanks. It's working. 
But I'm using '.mask("9999 9999 9999 9999")' and it doesn't work.

Comment: @easy_peasy, is that the jQuery mask plugin, or?

Comment: @easy_peasy, there you go. Try the last code snippet. :)

Comment: @Chris is "required" mandatory for this? Because thats the only thing I'm able to do that sets the input to invalid initially. "      <%= f.text_field :name, required: 'required' %>" works, but what if the name isn't mandatory? because       <%= f.text_field :name %> is ALWAYS valid

Comment: this is with rails btw... this is the rendered html when its not required: "<input type="text" name="project[name]" id="project_name">"

Answer (score 1):

In your code, the attribute maxlength="16" does not allow more than 16 characters to be typed in the input box. The regular expression you are using is valid when the input is between **0 and 16 characters**. Therefore, you regexp should be:

```
.{16,16}
```

And your HTML code:

```
<input type="text" pattern=".{16,16}" maxlength="16" required/>
```

You might want to see it working in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w4q8dxmw/3/).